# ReactGridLayout.children[0].y must be a number

Tags: react-grid-layout

I get the following error message when I'm trying to run the website in my development environment:

> Uncaught Error: ReactGridLayout:
> ReactGridLayout.children[0].y must be a number!
>
> at validateLayout (app.js:6171)
>
> at app.js:6132
>
> at forEachSingleChild (app.js:62734)
>
> at traverseAllChildrenImpl (app.js:62638)
>
> at traverseAllChildrenImpl (app.js:62654)
>
> at traverseAllChildren (app.js:62709)
>
> at Object.forEachChildren [as forEach] (app.js:62754)
>
> at synchronizeLayoutWithChildren (app.js:6117)
>
> at ReactGridLayout._initialiseProps (app.js:40638)
>
> at new ReactGridLayout (app.js:40089)

There is also an error telling me this:

> app.js:77841 The above error occurred in the  component:
>
> in ReactGridLayout (created by ResponsiveReactGridLayout)
>
> in ResponsiveReactGridLayout (created by WidthProvider)
>
> in WidthProvider (created by Grid)
>
> in div (created by Grid)
>
> in Grid (created by Test)
>
> in Test

This is my Test.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../../../public/css/app.css';
import '../../../public/css/all.css';
import Grid from '../components/Grid';

class Test extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <Grid/>
        )
    }
}

export default Test;

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

This is my Grid.jsx file:

```
import '../../../public/css/all.css';
import React from 'react';
import _ from "lodash";
import {WidthProvider, Responsive} from 'react-grid-layout';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
import Clock from './Clock.jsx';
import Weather from './Weather.jsx';

const ResponsiveReactGridLayout = WidthProvider(Responsive);
const originalLayouts = getFromLS("layouts") || [];

/* This class generates the layout for the web app. It renders the grid
 * and it's items, but also button's and a dropdown menu, to control the grid.
 */

class Grid extends React.PureComponent {
    static defaultProps = {
        className: "layout",
        cols: { lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2},
        rowHeight: 100,
        autoSize: true,
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: originalLayouts.map(function(i, key, list) {
                return {
                    i: originalLayouts[key].i,
                    x: originalLayouts[key].x,
                    y: originalLayouts[key].y,
                    w: originalLayouts[key].w,
                    h: originalLayouts[key].h,
                    widget: originalLayouts[key].widget,
                    minW: originalLayouts[key].minW,
                    minH: originalLayouts[key].minH,
                    maxH: originalLayouts[key].maxH
                };
            }),
            selectedOption: '',
            newCounter: originalLayouts.length
        };

        this.onAddItem = this.onAddItem.bind(this);
        this.onBreakPointChange = this.onBreakPointChange.bind(this);
        this.onLayoutChange = this.onLayoutChange.bind(this);
        this.onLayoutReset = this.onLayoutReset.bind(this);
    }

    /* This function renders all grid items in the layout array. It creates a div
     * with a remove button, and content. The content managed by a switch statement,
     * which output is based on the widget property from the grid items.
     */
    createElement(el) {
        const removeStyle = {
            position: 'absolute',
            right: '2px',
            top: 0,
            cursor: 'pointer'
        };
        const i = el.i;
        const widget = el.widget;

        return (
            <div key={i} data-grid={el}>
                {(() => {
                    switch(widget) {
                        case 'Clock':
                            return <Clock/>;
                        case 'Photo':
                            return <div className='photo'></div>;
                        case 'Weather':
                            return <Weather/>;
                        default:
                            return <span>{widget}</span>;
                    }
                })()}
                <span
                    className='remove'
                    style={removeStyle}
                    onClick={this.onRemoveItem.bind(this, i)} >
                    x
                </span>
            </div>
        );
    }

    /* The onAddItem() function is called when the user clicks on the 'Add Item' button.
     * It adds a new grid item to the state, and takes the selected item in the dropmenu
     * into account. This way the correct widget is loaded by the createElement() function.
     */
    onAddItem() {
        var selection = this.state.selectedOption ? this.state.selectedOption : 0;
        var widgetProps = returnProps(selection.value);

        if(selection) {
            console.log('adding', 'n' + this.state.newCounter + '; ' + selection.value);
        } else {
            console.log('adding', 'n' + this.state.newCounter + '; empty');
        }

        this.setState({
            items: this.state.items.concat({
                i: 'n' + this.state.newCounter,
                x: (this.state.items.length * 2) % (this.state.cols || 12),
                y: Infinity,
                w: widgetProps.w,
                h: widgetProps.h,
                widget: selection ? selection.value : '',
                minW: widgetProps.minW,
                minH: widgetProps.minH,
                maxH: widgetProps.maxH,
            }),
            newCounter: this.state.newCounter + 1
        });
    }

    /* onLayoutReset() is called when the user clicks on the 'Reset Layout' button.
     * It clears the localStorage and then issues a window refresh.
     */
    onLayoutReset() {
        localStorage.clear();
        window.location.reload();
    }

    /* Calls back with breakpoint and new # cols */
    onBreakPointChange(breakpoint, cols) {
        this.setState({
            breakpoint: breakpoint,
            cols: cols
        });
    }

    /* Is called whenever the layout is changed. The for loop adds widget attribute
     * from items array to objects in layout array, so that the widget props
     * are also saved to localStorage. This is because objects in the layout array
     * do not include a widget property by default.
     */
    onLayoutChange(layout) {
        this.setState({ layout: layout });
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
            layout[i].widget = this.state.items[i].widget;
        }
        saveToLS('layouts', layout);
    }

    /* When a user presses the little 'x' in the top right corner of a grid item,
     * this function is called. It removes the corresponding grid item.
     */
    onRemoveItem(i) {
        this.setState({ items: _.reject(this.state.items, {i: i }) });
    }

    /* handleChange passes the selected dropdown item to the state. */
    handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
        this.setState({ selectedOption });
        if (selectedOption) {
            console.log(`Selected: ${selectedOption.label}`);
        }
    };

    /* This render function, renders the grid, dropdown-menu, 'Add Item'-button
     * and 'Reset Layout'-button. This is also where the createElement() function
     * is called for each grid item.
     */
    render() {
        const { selectedOption } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className='widgetselecter'>
                    <Select className='dropdown'
                            name="form-field-name"
                            value={selectedOption}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            options={[
                                { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
                                { value: 'Clock', label: 'Clock' },
                                { value: 'Photo', label: 'Photo' },
                                { value: 'Weather', label: 'Weather' },
                            ]}
                    />
                    <button className='addButton' onClick={this.onAddItem}>Add Item</button>
                    <button className='reset' onClick={this.onLayoutReset}>Reset Layout</button>
                    <span className='title'>/Dash</span>
                </div>
                <ResponsiveReactGridLayout
                    onLayoutChange={this.onLayoutChange}
                    onBreakPointChange={this.onBreakPointChange}
                    {...this.props}>
                    {_.map(this.state.items, el => this.createElement(el))}
                </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

/* Retrieve layout from local storage. */
function getFromLS(key) {
    let ls = {};
    if (global.localStorage) {
        try {
            ls = JSON.parse(global.localStorage.getItem("rgl-8")) || {};
        } catch (e) {
            /*Ignore*/
        }
    }
    return ls[key];
}

/* Save layout to local storage. */
function saveToLS(key, value) {
    if (global.localStorage) {
        global.localStorage.setItem(
            "rgl-8",
            JSON.stringify({
                [key]: value
            })
        );
    }
}

/* returnProps function returns widget-specific properties like width, min width,
 * heigth, etc.
 */
function returnProps(selection) {
    switch(selection) {
        case 'Clock':
            return {
                w: 1.5,
                h: 1,
                minW: 1.5,
                minH: 1,
                maxH: 1000
            };
        case 'Weather':
            return {
                w: 3,
                h: 3,
                minW: 3,
                minH: 3,
                maxH: 3
            };
        default:
            return {
                w: 2,
                h: 2,
                minW: 1,
                minH: 1,
                maxH: 1000,
            };
    }
}

export default Grid;
```

I can't remember that I changed anything in the code and I also can't find anything related to the error message on Google. Can anyone tell me more about it or explain it to me? So i can look for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I had to change this bit of code:

```
        <ResponsiveReactGridLayout
            onLayoutChange={this.onLayoutChange}
            onBreakPointChange={this.onBreakPointChange}
            {...this.props}>
            {_.map(this.state.items, el => this.createElement(el))}
            >
        </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
```

to this:

```
        <ResponsiveReactGridLayout
            {...this.props}
            onBreakpointChange={this.onBreakpointChange}
            onLayoutChange={this.onLayoutChange}>
            {_.map(this.state.items, el => this.createElement(el))}
        </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
```

I think it has something to do with the order of rules of code and then especially this part:

```
                                            >
        {_.map(this.state.items, el => this.createElement(el))}
```

because this piece is outside the `<ResponsiveReactGridLayout>` now. I'm not sure if this is the right solution but it works for me. So if anyone has some additional information let me know please.